# DateTime Format provider for filepath

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, iformatprovider

I have a file-path that's been created from DateTime stamp:

```
"C:\\Logs\\Tests\\2015\\Mar\\24\\13_32_09\"
```

Now I am trying to convert my file-path back to DateTime object.

With Regex I can easily remove `"C:\\Logs\\Tests\"`, but now I am assume I need to provide implementation of **IFormtProvider** to convert `2015\\Mar\\24\\13_32_09\` into a **DateTime** object, but I haven't come along any similar example of how that's usually done.

Any example, may not be particular solution to my answer, would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015\\Mar\\24\\13_32_09\\", 
                                  @"yyyy\\MMM\\dd\\HH_mm_ss\\", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to create an `IFormatProvider` at all. The invariant culture is fine for this (assuming the month name is always in English). You can just use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss), passing in the appropriate [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4)  (quoting the literal characters, either with apostrophes around them or backslashes before them):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    text,
    @"yyyy'\'MMM'\'dd'\'HH'_'mm'_'ss'\'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that this assumes the path really *does* use backslashes... it won't work on Unix as-is. (You might want to canonicalize the directory separators first.)